# Downvote on a closed question causes decrease in asker's reputation? Is this new?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvoting

I had opened a question in Ask Ubuntu when I started using the site, without knowing much.

That question got closed as off topic. Here it is: https://askubuntu.com/q/99028/35775

Today I noticed that I had -2 rep change because of a down vote.

I didn't gave any answer. I thought that a downvote in an answer didn't change the user's reputation. Am I wrong, or has there been a new policy implemented?

Even if it is true that a down vote on a question causes negative rep, why is it the same for a closed question?  I don't see any reason for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone downvoted your question, you lose 2 reputation. But, on the other hand, if you downvote someone's question, you don't lose any rep.

This is similar to how the voting works on answer. If your answer is downvoted, you lose 2 reputation. If you downvoted an answer, you lose 1 rep. This is to prevent abuse of downvotes on competing answers.

In addition to all of these, if a question is closed as Not A real question or Off topic, a downvote is given to the question by the system.

Comment: Got it. `a downvote is given to the question by the system` is it implemented in recent time?

Comment: @Web-E No, its not a recent change.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this question on meta.SO about downvotes on closed questions, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112752/185528

Basically they let downvotes continue on closed questons so people can clean up their own content.